# Using bts assembly instruction with gcc compiler

Tags: c++, performance, macos, gcc, assembly

I want to use the bts and bt x86 assembly instructions to speed up bit operations in my C++ code on the Mac. On Windows, the _bittestandset and _bittest intrinsics work well, and provide significant performance gains. On the Mac, the gcc compiler doesn't seem to support those, so I'm trying to do it directly in assembler instead.

Here's my C++ code (note that 'bit' can be >= 32):

```
typedef unsigned long LongWord;
#define DivLongWord(w) ((unsigned)w >> 5)
#define ModLongWord(w) ((unsigned)w & (32-1))

inline void SetBit(LongWord array[], const int bit)
{
   array[DivLongWord(bit)] |= 1 << ModLongWord(bit);
}

inline bool TestBit(const LongWord array[], const int bit)
{
    return (array[DivLongWord(bit)] & (1 << ModLongWord(bit))) != 0;
}
```

The following assembler code works, but is not optimal, as the compiler can't optimize register allocation:

```
inline void SetBit(LongWord* array, const int bit)
{
   __asm {
      mov   eax, bit
      mov   ecx, array
      bts   [ecx], eax
   }
}
```

Question: How do I get the compiler to fully optimize around the bts instruction? And how do I replace TestBit by a bt instruction?

Comment: Not a direct answer, just a link to <a href="http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/info2html?(gcc)Extended%2520Asm">GCC Extended Asm</a> documentation.

Comment: `BT*` with a memory operand is slow, because of the crazy CISC semantics.  It's actually faster to let the compiler emit the shift/OR (or TEST) instruction sequence you'd get with this code.  (At least, a bugfixed and 64bit clean version of this).

Comment: For the performance of BT* (and other) instructions see: https://www.agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inline void SetBit(*array, bit) {
    asm("bts %1,%0" : "+m" (*array) : "r" (bit));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That helped me figure out my second question:

inline bool TestBit(const LongWord array[], const int bit)
{
   bool flag;
   asm("bt %2,%1; setb %0" : "=q" (flag) : "m" (*array), "r" (bit));
   return flag;
}

Comment: @ephemient: Can you please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: If `bit` might be outside the 0..31 range, your memory operand should be the whole array, not just the first element of it.  (Remember the crazy-CISC bit-string semantics of [`bts`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BTS.html) with a memory operand.)  Also, you should let the source operand be `"ri"`, because it works with immediate operands (and is much less slow that way).  But really you shouldn't use this at all on modern x86.  `bts` with a memory operand is *slow* (see my answer).

Comment: This instruction mangles C flag, but the assembly doesn't specify that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: A "cc" clobber is implicit in GNU C inline asm for x86 and x86-64.  That's not a bug, although some people consider it good style to manually specify it anyway.

Answer (score 8):

`BTS` (and the other `BT*` insns) with a memory destination [are slow.  (>10 uops on Intel)](http://agner.org/optimize/).  You'll probably get faster code from doing the address math to find the right byte, and loading it into a register.  Then you can do the `BT` / `BTS` with a register destination and store the result.

Or maybe shift a `1` to the right position and use `OR` with with a memory destination for SetBit, or `AND` with a memory source for `TestBit`.  Of course, if you avoid inline asm, the compiler can inline `TestBit` and use `TEST` instead of `AND`, which is useful on some CPUs (since it can macro-fuse into a test-and-branch on more CPUs than `AND`).

[This is in fact what gcc 5.2 generates from your C source](http://goo.gl/c4rxpF) (memory-dest `OR` or `TEST`).  Looks optimal to me (fewer uops than a memory-dest `bt`).  Actually, note that your code is broken because it assumes `unsigned long` is 32 bits, not `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned_long)`.  Using `uint32_t`, or `char`, would be a much better plan.  Note the sign-extension of `eax` into `rax` with the `cqde` instruction, due to the badly-written C which uses `1` instead of `1UL`.

Also note that inline asm can't return the flags as a result (except with a [new-in-gcc v6 extension!](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands)), so using inline asm for TestBit would probably result in terrible code code like:

```
...  ; inline asm
bt   reg, reg
setc al       ; end of inline asm
test al, al   ; compiler-generated
jz bit_was_zero
```

Modern compilers can and do use `BT` when appropriate (with a register destination).  End result: your C probably compiles to faster code than what you're suggesting doing with inline asm.  It would be even faster after being bugfixed to be correct and 64bit-clean.  If you were optimizing for code size, and willing to pay a significant speed penalty, forcing use of `bts` could work, but `bt` probably still won't work well (because the result goes into the flags).

Comment: Actually, as of v6, gcc [can](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands) return flags.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Thanks!  That's interesting that they finally included that.

Comment: @PeterCordes have you ever seen a compiler generate `bts`? I could indeed get at least `clang` and `icc` to generate `bt` for "test bit" type [functions](https://godbolt.org/g/xx3v1x) but didn't have any luck with `bts` even though it would seem very useful for "set bit" type function compared to the alternatives of using `shl` or `shlx` and `or` and a couple extra ops to load the constant `1` etc.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I forget.  What you describe sounds familiar: using `bt` for testing bits, but failing to use `bts` for set-bit.  I'm pretty sure it's a win on Intel CPUs at least, for stuff like `foo |= 1<<n`, where `n` is not a compile-time constant and foo is already in a register.  Yeah, just tested, and no luck: https://godbolt.org/g/9s6i9D

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the idom I tested in the godbolt link. I _did_ find a way to generate `bts` on `icc` only, in the specific case of a [compile-time bit index](https://godbolt.org/g/wuxMcm). Neither `gcc` nor `clang` use `bts` there, and `icc` doesn't use it if the position is variable (where it is arguably even more useful, since the non-`bts` code for variable shifts is generally even slower than the constant case, especially pre-`SHLX`).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: huh, interesting use-case.  I guess `or r64, imm32` wouldn't work there, because the constant can't be represented as a sign-extended imm32.  Agreed that using it for variable-shifts is a bigger win.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: re: lack of recent answers.  Not exactly, but I was getting tired of seeing the same newbie questions all the time so I took a break for SO for a while to catch up on TV / movies / books I'd been wanting to watch/read.

Comment: @PeterCordes, duh, good point. I had only tested it with such a large constant due to copy-pasting from another test: but I hadn't explicitly intended to use 64-bit. Of course for 32-bit constants `or` is usually better due to more execution units and faster average speed across many architectures (`bts` hasn't been 1 cycle forever, AFAIK). Indeed, everyone uses `or` for 32-bit or less constants (you could still make a minor case for `bts` since it is 5 bytes vs `or`-with-32-bit-constant's 7 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

This version efficiently returns the carry flag (via the gcc-v6 extension mentioned by Peter in the top answer) for a subsequent test instruction. It only supports a register operand since use of a memory operand is very slow as he said:

```
int variable_test_and_set_bit64(unsigned long long &n, const unsigned long long bit) {
    int oldbit;
    asm("bts %2,%0"
        : "+r" (n), "=@ccc" (oldbit)
        : "r" (bit));
    return oldbit;
}
```

Use in code is then like so. The wasSet variable is optimized away and the produced assembly will have bts followed immediately by jb instruction checking the carry flag.

```
unsigned long long flags = *(memoryaddress);
unsigned long long bitToTest = someOtherVariable;
int wasSet = variable_test_and_set_bit64(flags, bitToTest);
if(!wasSet) {
  *(memoryaddress) = flags;
}
```

Although it seems a bit contrived, this does save me several instructions vs the "1ULL << bitToTest" version.

Comment: Nice, thanks for writing this up.  Ideally, GCC should use `bts reg,reg` itself when optimizing pure C, and it does in a few cases (like with non-pointers), but not with `mem[pos/32] |= 1<<(pos%32)`  (https://godbolt.org/z/an6W1nqTq).  It's had that missed optimization bug for years now; so does clang.  Related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80813 re: using `bt` for read-only check of a bit-array.

Answer (score -1):

Another slightly indirect answer, GCC exposes [a number of atomic operations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins) starting with version 4.1.