# assembly intrinsic for atomic bit test and set (BTS)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, atomic

`struct node* address; //format <addr,flagBit1,flagBit2>`

I want to use BTS to **atomically** set the `flagBit1` bit.

**EDIT**

**I want to blindly set this bit without caring about if it was previously set or not**

I can use assembly code to get this done as suggested in [Using bts assembly instruction with gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983303/using-bts-assembly-instruction-with-gcc-compiler)

But  is there an intrinsic I can use which is portable across different architectures?

For instance, [gcc Atomic Builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) has `__sync_fetch_and_or`. Does this have the same property as BTS?

Comment: Yes, but see this [gcc bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49244).

Comment: @Jester: Thanks for the reference. I'm not interested in the previous value of `flagBit`. I just want to blindly set it without caring if it was previously set or not

Comment: If you don't need atomicity, the comments in gcc seem to say that using bts is likely to slow your code down...

Comment: I need atomicity. Else I would rather use bitwise operation. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Can you use C11? Support is pretty thin for now, but it should provide a suitable atomic operation. Otherwise, the __sync builtins should work (though they won't use bts currently). Note that they were replaced: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html (though the __sync versions have the advantage that several compilers implement them).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Are you suggesting me to use `__atomic_test_and_set`?

Comment: More like __atomic_or_fetch or __atomic_fetch_or, no?

Comment: What is the difference between `atomic_or_fetch` and `atomic_fetch_or`

Comment: The `atomic_or_fetch` does the `or` first and returns the result, the other returns the original value.

Comment: The final result of both should be the same, right? If yes, then since I don't care what was stored previously I can use both safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a blind setting of a bit, `sync_fetch_and_or` or `sync_or_and_fetch` seem to be both equally good, with the result discarded the compiler knows to optimize it out.
On x86 gcc won't use `bts`, instead it will simply do a `lock or` which should be fine.

Comment: gcc-10.1 emits `lock bts` for `atomic<unsigned>::fetch_or(bits, mo_relaxed)`.