# C, compound assignment - arithmetic operation, conversion may loose information

Tags: c

Is there a way to write the operation short and suppress the warning?

```
BYTE data[10];
int i = 0;    
int offset = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    // some code
    data[offset] |= (1 << i);  // WARNING: conversion may loose information
}
```

my attempts:

```
data[offset] |= (BYTE) (1 << i); // failed
data[offset] |= (1 << (BYTE) i); // failed
```

Compiler: TIA-V13 WinCC from Siemens

**Solution**: No compound assignment operators!

Comment: There is no `short`. And show the definition of `BYTE`.

Comment: You may want to add the compiler info that produces the warning and how `BYTE` is defined.

Comment: This code is correct and your compiler is giving a false warning.  Perhaps investigate how to turn off that warning for this section of code, or consult your compiler documentation for this warning.  To get answers about a specific compiler you will have to mention which compiler and version you are using

Comment: 1 - Please show definition of `BYTE` (I assume it is `short`). 2 - Let us know the size in bytes of the type `BYTE` and/or `short` on your machine. 3 - Show us a copy of the output please.

Comment: You can use bts assembly instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983303/using-bts-assembly-instruction-with-gcc-compiler

Comment: @M.M: The warning is nasty, but actually correct. e.g. gcc generates such warnings.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what flags? `gcc -pedantic -Wall` does not issue anything, with `BYTE` either as `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`. I *do* get your error when I typedef `BYTE` as something totally illogical, such as `float`.

Comment: @Jongware: For gcc it is `-Wconversion`. Bad enough; the switch is otherwise very useful.

Comment: @sibnick: I'd rather use `pragmas` around before before reverting to assembler just to suppress a warning. This is not about optimising.

Comment: WHy is the compiler warning even an issue to begin with. If you know your code is correct, and doing exactly what you want, why do you care about compiler warnings on it?

Comment: @Magisch: Many development standards make warnings errors and require compilation without any warning. The option which generates these warnings are very useful in general, so one should enable it. And there are very well use-cases of a compound-assignments which should be warned about.

Comment: @Olaf the warning is not correct. The warning says "may lose information" however there is no possibility for this code to lose information.

Comment: @M.M: It very well does: `1 << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` will (presuming the it is the MSB) loose the sign of the result.

Comment: @Olaf your expression does not appear in OP's code. `1` is shifted by a maximum of `6` bits.

Comment: @M.M: You cannot expect the compiler to perform a full dynamic code analysis to suppress the warning. As give, the compiler _has to assume_ `i` is an arbitrary, yet valid, value.

Comment: @Olaf I am saying that the warning message is false for this exact code. I'm not making any statement about what a compiler should or should not do.

Comment: @M.M: False? Nope. But unwarranted. As are many warnings which are safely silenced by explicit casts, as it is possibly for this warning, too. Do you really expect a compiler to analyse the code for every warning if it is suitable?

Comment: @Olaf it is false. The warning says "may lose information" but in fact no information can be lost by this exact code.  Please re-read my last comment: I do not make any statement about what the compiler should do. I am only commenting on whether or not this code may lose information.  Please explain how you think information is lost in OP's exact code.

Comment: @M.M: Ok, last try: The warning says "...**may** loose information", which include the no-lose case. Thus the warning is true. Anything else has already been written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not define `BYTE`; I'll assume it is identical to `stdint.h`s `uint8_t` (which should always be preferred to homebrew types).

`a |= b` (roughly) translates to `a = a | b`, including *integer promotions* here as part of the *usual arithmetic conversions*. For the types given this means `a` is converted to `int` before the operation is performed, yielding an `int` result. The final assignment will truncate this `int` for the assignment, possibly loosing information (likely the sign), because `int` is at least 16 bits wide.

Casting `b` does not help, because the conversion is done for the operation and you have to cast the result.

The transformation is also the solution:

```
uint8_t a;
a = (uint8_t)(a | b);
```

Explicitly tells the compiler you know what you do and to shut up. Just make sure you **really** know what you do!

This is not very elegant, but the only way to suppress the warning. OTOH the behaviour is arithmetically consistent with the simple assignment-version.

Edit: You should use unsigned integer constants when shifting where possible. Even more, as you operate on unsigned variables anyway. As a general rule, try to avoid mixing signed and unsigned operands. If that is not possible make sure you know what is going on and catch all invalid cases.

Edit2: For some implementations/signed integer representations and some combinations for types and operations, it is possible to prove no information can be lost, thus the warning is obsolete. However, it seems this would require knowledege of machine details which might not be available at the stage the warning is generated.

Maybe the C standard should have defined the compound assignment to implicitly include the final cast. That would not be the only legacy. OTOH, this behaviour might have generated confusion in the other direction to people which were not aware of this (note that in C an assignment yields a result!). Which is the lesser of two evils?

Comment: I can agree with your thorough explanation. Except that if all operands of bitwise OR are bytes then any integer promotion before the operation can never result in loss of information when the compiler truncates the result back to a byte. And the compiler should know this and (indeed) shut up.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Well, it **can**. That because the operation is performed `int`, thus signed. Anyway, the standard does not go that far actually. It just converts the operands to `int` (so the `|` **is** performed on `int`, not `uint8_t`) and the result is `int`, too. Note that things become even more complicated if the result was e.g.  `int8_t`. Then the result was implementation-specific. So, while I too find this behaviour somewhat nasty, it is correct.

Comment: No, it _can't_ ;oose information. Sign-extending a byte and applying bitwise OR and then truncating back to byte will still not loose any information. Yes, the upper sign-extended one bits are lost, but they were never a part of the byte anyway. Again, in my opinion the compiler should know and shut up.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: You just think about 2s complement representation. But the standard does not require this, but also e.g. sign/magnitude, which would loose the sign very well.

Comment: The compiler is TIA-V13 WinCC from Siemens. I've not defined BYTE and i can't find the definition. And i cannot tell the compiler to ignore this warning. The only way is: the long arithmetic operation. ``data[offset] = (BYTE)(data[offset] | (1 << i));``

Comment: I don't know what compiler that is, but I have the same issue with gcc. And yes, you need a _simple assignment_, not a [_compound asignment_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2). Is that what you called "short arithmetic operation? - if so, please use the correct name; `short` and `long` are C integer datatypes which interferes with the subject of your question.

Comment: Yes, i mean compound assignment. ``short`` is not the data type, sorry.

Comment: Using a cast in `a = (uint8_t)(a|b)` is not a "requirement by the standard". According to the standard, this is exactly identical to `a |= b`.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as *default integer conversions*.

Comment: @M.M: It is not **exactly** identical, but equivalent with some [exceptions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p3). For the "default integer conversions": You are right, there is no such term. The correct prase would be _integer promotions_ which are part of the _usual arithmetic conversions_. Edited. But the intention should be clear.

Comment: @M.M: The part about "requirement by the standard was badly worded.